# Rsync only files from specific user

Tags: rsync

Is there a way to rsync only files from a certain user? I have a folder which contains files from multiple users but would only like to backup files from a particular user.

I've looked at the man pages for rsync but there doesn't seem to be such a flag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to single out, directly from the rsync command line, the files of a specific user.

It is however very easy to generate a list of these files, for instance with a command like

```
   find /src/directory -type f -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{if ($3 == "your_name") for (i=1; i<=NF-8; i++) $i = $(i+8); NF-=8; print}'
```

`find` finds all the files in the tree below the /src/directory, and prints out a long listing which includes the owner, then passes these listings to `awk`, which selects those that belong to you ("your_name") and then, only for these, prints out the full path. The strange construct beginning with `for` is due to the fact that some of the file names might include a space, so this construct prints all tokens (`i.e.`, all space-delimited character sequences) from the 9th column on (file names might include an arbitrary number of spaces). Also, this construct makes sure this stays on a single line.

You may re-direct this output to a file, and then use rsync only on the files listed in this file.

Answer (score 0):

MariusMatutiae's answer didn't work for me:
I got there masses of `-rw-r--r--` lines only.

So I developed this answer:

1. The `find` command has option `-user` (and `-group`) which is much easier to use. We need relative path/filenames:
   a) `find` option: `-printf '%P\n'`, or
   b) pipe through `sed -e "s#/path##"`
2. rsync offers the possibility to sync from files:
   `--files-from=FILE`.
   You need this file local. So you have to push rsync the files,
   or the server which pulls must get it first from remote side where
   the list has been generated before.

=> For my example this works:
1a) `find /usr/share/piwik/ -user www-data -printf '%P\n' > /tmp/find-piwik-rsync.list`, or
1b) `find /usr/share/piwik/ -user www-data | sed -e "s#/usr/share/piwik/##" > /tmp/find-piwik-rsync.list`

2) `rsync -a --files-from=/tmp/find-piwik-rsync.list /usr/share/piwik/ remote:/usr/share/piwik`

You should first test it with `-n` / `--dry-run`.